# Как написать правильно регулярку чтобы каждый символ обернуть в span кроме br и удалить все пробелы

Tags: javascript, html

Сам пытался написать но не вышло

```js
let txt = document.querySelector('.app__title');

document.write(txt.innerHTML.replace(/(?![^<]*>)[^\s*/]/g, c => `<span>${c}</span>\n`));
```

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, так?

```js
const txt = document.querySelector('.app__title');

for (const node of [...txt.childNodes]) {
  if (node.nodeType !== Node.TEXT_NODE) continue;

  const text = node.textContent.replace(/\s/g, '');
  const fragment = new DocumentFragment();
  for (const character of text) {
    const span = document.createElement('span');
    span.textContent = character;
    fragment.appendChild(span);
  }
  txt.replaceChild(fragment, node);
}
```

```css
.app__title{
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
        <h2 class="app__title">
                        時間が経つほど<br class="md">「選んでよかった」
                    </h2>
```

Comment: да, только надо так что бы любой br с классом или без него  всегда оставался

Comment: Тогда, увы, придётся воздержаться от регулярок, потому что полноценный парсинг HTML регулярками делать не советуют, они для этого плохо предназначены. Тогда стоит перебрать подэлементы, выбрать из них текстовые, убрать пробелы и заменить каждый из оставшихся символов на `span`, а затем заменить текстовый узел на коллекцию элементов. Я изменил ответ.

Comment: забавно, обычно вместо конструктора [`document.createDocumentFragment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment) был

Comment: Спасибо) очень помог